# Get Freeswitch events via SIP NOTIFY

Tags: events, sip, notify, freeswitch, subscribe

Freeswitch server has a lot of events and can be handled with event_socket_libray.

I want to subscribe to those events from a sip client and get notified if a particular event is fired.

Any Idea how to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate NOTIFY events by firing specially crafted events via ESL:  http://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2012-October/088961.html

So, you need a software agent that listens to events of your interest and then sends the NOTIFY events. Should be quite easy to do with any programming language that you prefer. You can also use some other means to deliver the messages -- for example, push them into a Redis queue.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your reply. I appreciate your help. My ultimate interest is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891505/voicemail-detection-on-freeswitch